# Gwt-rpc usage DAO only. Get rid of DTO

Tags: gwt, serialization, dao, dto, gwt-rpc

I am about to start new java project and I consider GWT as my framework for it.

I've checked a lot of articles on the internet (main documentation also) and I am quite confused.

So I ask You:

Can I use jpa Entities to work with DAO, and to be sended over network to client?

I really don't understand the concept of DTO (writing almost the same but more poor class of Model)

If I will about to send Entities over network to client, how to use Serializable Transient annotation to NOT serialize and send methods, parameters of class? Is it even possible?

How all of this will work with Generic Typed Superclass extended by right class implementation?

f.e:

```
public class GenericModel extends GenericModel<T> {
     //some generic code
}

public class RightModel extends GenericModel<RightModel> {
    // some right class code
}
```

the same goes with DAO...

Please help.
I count on Yours experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I was an expert at that time but when I started to combine Hibernate (not JPA as such) and GWT, it was a pain.

The reason that you can't just send over Hibernate managed objects (and I guess same counts for JPA, regardless of the underlying technology), is that they contain bytecode-manipulation stuff like *javassist*. GWT doesn't like this at all, and you can't send those objects over the GWT RPC wire.

Ofcourse also it doesn't make sense: you can't expect your Javascript (client-side) to invoke SQL to lazy-load collections when you invoke a getter on your DAO (because that's what happens server-side with these DAO objects, that's what the javassist magic is doing behind your back).

I'm not sure that even if all collections were eagerly loaded, your objects would be free of javassist stuff, and could be serialized over GWT-RPC. That leaves you with one alternative, which is to have POJO objects tailor-made to contain only those parts (properties/collections) that you need on the client at that moment - the DTO.

Since then a lot has happened in GWT, and I know of something completely different from RPC, which is RequestFactory (see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html). I haven't used that myself, but it claims to `make it easy to build data-oriented (CRUD) apps with an ORM-like interface on the client`. So this may be the way to go if you don't want to build custom classes for wiring RPC.